# How to access members of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I have been trying to access the elements of a nested object but still have no success. I searched through existing similar questions on stackexchange (eg: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)) but could not resolve my issue.
I tried to access the final element using **console.log(result.final)** but it shows **undefined** in the console. Kindly advise.

```
var data = '{"response":{"valid":true,"final":{"message":" MS02","tags":{"d1":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9","d2":"JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC","d3":"dupb9WWT8ypQYWw6QblkM98xFBBRsamkkWLw","d5":"5EChV1KJ4ASeh9crZDR3fivnSz4wCDmCr2RSC0CUrkx","d6":"hiH1I1SI3NHCYZeva0_FrjgSgxOa_YW6ECxRdAY-w5w","ua":"y"},"ti":"","op":[]}}}';
var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
var result = [];

result = Object.entries(dataJson).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
console.log(result)
console.log(result.final)
```

**UPDATE**
I used `typeof` on `dataJson` and it showed it as a `string` so I did `JSON.parse` one more time on `dataJson` and then checked again with `typeof` which showed `object` and now after double `JSON.parse` I was able to access the nested values with dot operator (result.final), without mapping.

Comment: Try `console.log(result[0].response.final)`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're mapping the `dataJson` to `result`, when you can access `final` just by using `dataJson.response.final` ?

Comment: @Pantalaimon No specific reason. I am unable to access value using ‘’’dataJson.response.final’’’

Comment: @danh it didn’t work

Comment: @Crunch - see the snippet. OP code exactly, plus `console.log(result[0].response.final)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been given multiple answers that work just fine based on the code that you've provided. Like I said in a comment earlier, you don't need to map the data to an array first before accessing its data.

```js
var data = '{"response":{"valid":true,"final":{"message":" MS02","tags":{"d1":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9","d2":"JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC","d3":"dupb9WWT8ypQYWw6QblkM98xFBBRsamkkWLw","d5":"5EChV1KJ4ASeh9crZDR3fivnSz4wCDmCr2RSC0CUrkx","d6":"hiH1I1SI3NHCYZeva0_FrjgSgxOa_YW6ECxRdAY-w5w","ua":"y"},"ti":"","op":[]}}}';
var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(dataJson.response.final);
```

If this doesn't work for you, then the information you've given might be incorrect or incomplete. Please provide for us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clearly demonstrates the issue you're having.

Comment: Actually this piece of code exists inside success block of an ajax call. Data is received after the successful ajax call. console.log(result) shows we received data. But when I try to access as above, it didn’t work. Do i need to do something else for ajax success part?

Comment: @Crunch Can you post the full code of the ajax call and the **success** method? Can you also verify that the value of the `data` variable is *exactly* the JSON that you've posted? My guess is that your JSON is somehow different than you expect it to be, if our solutions don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
console.log(result[0].response.final)
```

Not a js developer so maybe somebody can provide better solution

Comment: it didn’t work i tried it already

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code, changed only to log correctly...

```js
var data = '{"response":{"valid":true,"final":{"message":" MS02","tags":{"d1":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9","d2":"JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC","d3":"dupb9WWT8ypQYWw6QblkM98xFBBRsamkkWLw","d5":"5EChV1KJ4ASeh9crZDR3fivnSz4wCDmCr2RSC0CUrkx","d6":"hiH1I1SI3NHCYZeva0_FrjgSgxOa_YW6ECxRdAY-w5w","ua":"y"},"ti":"","op":[]}}}';
var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
var result = [];

result = Object.entries(dataJson).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
console.log(result)
console.log(result[0].response.final)
```

Comment: Actually this piece of code exists inside **success** block of an ajax call. Data is received after the successful ajax call.  console.log(result) shows we received data. But when I try to access as above, it didn’t work. Do i need to do something else for ajax success part?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to help based on what's described here.  The best path to fix is to debug (or log) at each line, stopping when you see something unexpected, then -- if necessary -- posting exactly that code, exactly what the log says, and how it differs from your expectation.